# CSS in ReactJS - media query and grouping selectors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

How can I use next 2 `CSS` examples in React to act exactly as I would do it in plain `CSS/HTML`, but without using `danerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .main {
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
}

.un:active, .pass:active {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) !important;
}
```

I did tried to Google those 2 cases but there wasn't anything that covers them.

EDIT: There is much more css behind the scene and I want to transform that css and html to React component. The problem is that I don't know how to transform media query from plain CSS into React. I want for that media query to be applied on entire Component. I know how to transform CSS to React in general, but I have this specific situation (I am still new to React) when there is media query and grouping selectors and I don't know how to transform those in React to be used in that component for only that component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `danerouslySetInnerHTML` is not a proper way to add `CSS` to a `react` application, there are many ways to add `CSS`, for example I use `PostCSS` preprocessor and for example `Less`, `Sass`, `SCSS`, `JSS` and many other ways are exist that you can use them, *But* if you just wanna run a test, make a `style` tag and put these two `CSS`es in it and absolutely your browser find it out and show you the results like plain `HTML/CSS`.

Do like this below code:

```
<style>
    @media (max-width: 600px) {
       .main {
           border-radius: 0px;
       }
    }

    .un:active, .pass:active {
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18) !important;
    }
</style>
```

And put it in your code. Undoubtedly it works.

But with your more explain and editing the question, I understand that you need `JSS` for your work, for more information visit [this link](http://cssinjs.org)

You can use in inside of your `react` app with less complexity. you can prepare your `CSS`es just like you want, as a `JavaScript` object:

```
const viewPortSizes = { 
    height: "100vh",
    width: "100vw",
};
```

And then use it in your `JSX` tags.

Hope it helps you.